# dspam crashes with “general protection” kernel error

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, kernel, dspam

I use DSpam with Postfix. Recently DSpam started to crash with the following error in syslog:

```
Nov 16 14:10:55 home kernel: [  133.042190] traps: dspam[1692] general protection ip:7f63a493f3b0 sp:7f639adb6c60 error:0 in libc-2.17.so[7f63a48bf000+1bd000]
```

I can bring DSpam up again with `service dspam start`, then `postfix flush` to get things going again. A handful of emails (~5) will get scanned and delivered before DSpam crashes again.

The setup:

- DSpam 3.10.2
- Postfix 2.10.2
- Ubuntu 13.04 x64 (Digital Ocean droplet)

Answer (score 1):

Either you have bad RAM on your server (hopefully unlikely, but with DO, you never know...), or there is a bug in the version you are using, or it is corrupt, or your distribution has shipped binary-incompatible libraries.

Consider updating everything with apt.  If you have a reason to suspect it might be a hardware problem, bother DO's support.

Comment: It used to work flawlessly, and DO claims that the droplet hasn't been modified, so maybe it is bad RAM.